# Do I need to remove observer manually if I want it to be there for the entire app life time?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, observers

My NSNotification Observer is not just for a certain view or view controller. I want it to be removed only when users close the app. I put the "add observer" in AppDelegate. Do I still need to remove it in deinit manually or it gets removed automatically when the app is closed?

Comment: are you adding observer in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: @Vvk Yes I added it there

Comment: you have to remove observer in `applicationWillTerminate` method in AppDelegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want notification for certain view controller then please add `add observer` to that particular classes and `remove observer` in `viewDidDisappear`.  Ae seen your case, right now you have added `add observer` in `app delegate` , then you can remove it in below methods according to your requirements.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application 
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 1):

When the app is terminate then a method call i.e.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. 
}
```

you can remove the observer:

or you cal remove the observer here:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
```

When application come in background.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should write your code in

```
 deinit{
   //remove observer here
}
```

Add above method in Appdelegate class.

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

you have to addobserver in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(<#your selector#>)
                                                 name:@"TestNotification"
                                               object:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

then remove observer in `applicationWillTerminate`. you not need to remove observer in other methods because many times app going to background and not calling `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` all time. so you have to remove  in `applicationWillTerminate` only.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

    // If you don't remove yourself as an observer, the Notification Center
    // will continue to try and send notification objects to the deallocated
    // object.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

hope it helps you.